# How to automatically change values of input text box based on change in combo box selection using php and html

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html

Lets say there is a combobox with 3 values:a,b,c. There are also 3 text boxes. There is a database with 1 table which contains 4 columns. Now, how exactly can I update the values of the 3 inputboxes whenever I select a different value in the combobox. Lets say combobox represents the data in column 1 of the database table, textbox1 reporesents data for column 2, textbox2 for column3 and textbox3 for column4, so that the values of the text input boxes changes accordingly.

I am really sorry for being vague. Hope someone can still help me out. This has to be done using php html ajax and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

this has to be done in javascript mainly.
something like this (no valid code just mockup)

```
<select onchange="changeInputBoxes(this)"...> .... </select>
<script>
function changeInputBoxes(){
document.getElementById("inputid").value = this.value;
...
}
</script>
```

but its really to vague.

Comment: the data is coming from a database, they are not fixed data. So, I don't think this will work.

Comment: i cant help you without more details